# Python - dividing a list-of-lists to groups

Tags: python, list, performance, memory-efficient

Consider the following simplified case:

```
lol = [['John','Polak',5,3,7,9],
       ['John','Polak',7,9,2,3],
       ['Mark','Eden' ,0,3,3,1],
       ['Mark','Eden' ,5,1,2,9]]
```

What would be a **pythonic and memory+speed efficient** way to transform this list-of-lists to a list-of-lists-of-lists based on the first two parameters:

```
lolol = [[['John','Polak',5,3,7,9],
          ['John','Polak',7,9,2,3]],
         [['Mark','Eden' ,0,3,3,1],
          ['Mark','Eden' ,5,1,2,9]]]
```

Actually - any other data structure would also be ok, as long as I have the correct hierarchy. For example the following dictionary structure comes to mind, but creating it doesn't seem efficient speed-efficient enough, and the memory would probably be higher than the lolol solution.

```
dolol = {('John','Polak'):[[5,3,7,9],[7,9,2,3]],
         ('Mark','Eden') :[[0,3,3,1],[5,1,2,9]]}
```

Comment: is the input list always going to be sorted by key, or might it be in mixed order?

Comment: How would a dict be inefficient? I.e. what do you want to do with the data (that would make dicts inefficient)?

Comment: @Jesse - Yes, the keys are a priori sorted and that is definitely my need. Although for curiosity I wouldn't mind knowing the other case as well.

Comment: @delnan - as dict is hashed, creating it would take more time, also the hash would consume more memory. I'm not sure how much, but I am dealing with hundreds of mega of data so it could get messy...

Comment: @Jonathan: A dict does take more memory, but not significantly more time if you're ever going to search for something in it.

Comment: You might think about using a class, considering your data will probably be more meaningful in that context. To keep it memory-efficient, use the `__slots__` builtin.

Comment: @delnan - after creating the new data structure, I only need to traverse it once linearly

Comment: @Johnathan: In that case, go with @tokland's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complement delnan's answer with a Python 2 equivalent:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dolol=defaultdict(list)
for data in lol:
    dolol[data[0],data[1]].append(data[2:])
```

Answer (score 6):

List:

```
from itertools import groupby
lolol = [list(grp) for (match, grp) in groupby(lol, lambda lst: lst[:2])]
# [[['John', 'Polak', 5, 3, 7, 9], ['John', 'Polak', 7, 9, 2, 3]],
#  [['Mark', 'Eden', 0, 3, 3, 1], ['Mark', 'Eden', 5, 1, 2, 9]]]
```

Dictionary:

```
dolol = dict((tuple(match), [x[2:] for x in grp]) for (match, grp) in 
             groupby(lol, lambda lst: lst[:2]))
# {('John', 'Polak'): [[5, 3, 7, 9], [7, 9, 2, 3]],
#  ('Mark', 'Eden'): [[0, 3, 3, 1], [5, 1, 2, 9]]}
```

Since `itertools.groupby` works on consecutive matches, it assumes sorted input (`lol`).

Answer (score 5):

If a dictionary is acceptable, this code will create one:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for name, surname, *stuff in lol:
    d[name, surname].append(nums)
```

Note that this requires Python 3 ([extended iterable unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)). For Python 2, use

```
for x in lol:
    name = x[0]
    surname = x[1]
    stuff = x[2:]
```

You may fold the variables to save lines.